# Getting "JPEGDecompressSurface : Picture decode failed:" on creating UIImage from JPG raw data on iOS 10

Tags: ios

Since update to iOS 10, I'm getting the following error when creating UIImage from NSMutableData:

> JPEGDecompressSurface  : Picture decode failed:e000....."

There is no strange or not normal behaviour resulting, but when I debug my application I see the error quite each time I create the Image.

Here is the code, where I create the image from downloaded data using `GCDAsynchSocket` class:

```
NSData *imgDataToGen = [NSData dataWithData:imgBuffer];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgDataToGen];
[_delegate client:self didReceiveImage:img];
```

The buffer `imgBuffer` is a `NSMutableData-Object`, which holds the downloaded image data. When the download is complete the data is converted into a picture and passed to the main GUI by firing the custom delegate method. In the main GUI then the image is set in image View.
Once an image is processed, the buffer is cleared.

I tried different things, like forcing the decoding of the UIImage already in background thread, but I get always same error. The image is rendered always in right way, so I  really don't understand the error message.

I tried on `iPhone 5c` with `iOS 10.0.2` and on `Simulator 5s` with `iOS 9.2` and `10.0.2`.

On `iPhone 5c` I get the error, on simulator not.

How can I fix this error, or can this type of error be ignored?

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Count me in -- I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: I'm struggling with the very same problem (streaming images from a MOBOTIX security cam), interestingly though not on all devices – did you check on the iOS simulator and do you also get this when you skip the background predecoding?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved. 
In my case, I didn't notice but the conversion from Data to UIImage and the saving was performed in the main thread, once I dispatched it async to the global queue with background QOS priority and only the refresh of the GUI UIImage I dispatched back to main queue, the error stop showing in the debugger.
I hope it helps you.

Example:

```
fileprivate func downloadFromURL(urlString:String, callback:((_ image:UIImage?, _ error: Error?)->Void)?)   {
    var image: UIImage?
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        callback!(nil, iError.RuntimeError(reason: "Wrong URL for image".localized))
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                callback!(image,nil)
                return
            }

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            callback!(nil, iError.RuntimeError(reason: "Data error for image".localized))
            return

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added example to original post per ulmstefan request